# If statement inside JQuery $.each

Tags: jquery

I am using $.each to build HTML based on JSON Data.
I am trying to write if statement in that will show Extension number when its not null.

```
  var number='';
  $.each(abc[0].Phone, function (i, item) {
    number +=   '<p>Phone: ' + item.Phone + '' +(item.Extension !== null ? ' Ext#: ' + item.Extension : '')+  '</p>'; 
 });
```

After using this the Extension numbers still shows event if its empty.
Also, I am wondering if there is a way to add ELSE to the statement.

Comment: can you show us sample data of abc, so that we can give you your output result

Comment: Is `item.Extension` null - or is it just empty? There's a difference.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine from the inferred `abc` array structure: https://jsfiddle.net/qscghu22/1/. Please show a working example of the problem

Comment: item.Extension is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Extension value was empty not null .. Therefore: the code should be like this

```
 var number='';
  $.each(abc[0].Phone, function (i, item) {
    number +=   '<p>Phone: ' + item.Phone + '' +(item.Extension !== ""? ' Ext#: ' + item.Extension : '')+  '</p>'; 
 });
```

Thanks for  @thebluefox and  @Rory McCrossan for bring it to my mind